# JavaScript Konami code issues. Code included

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeydown

I am totally new to JavaScript so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I would appreciate if anybody can tell me what am I doing wrong (the alert "Hurray" is not triggered). Here is the code:

```
const codes = [
  "ArrowUp",
  "ArrowUp",
  "ArrowDown",
  "ArrowDown",
  "ArrowLeft",
  "ArrowRight",
  "ArrowLeft",
  "ArrowRight",
  "b",
  "a"
];

let index = 0;

function init() {
  document.body.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {

    function onKeyDownHandler(e) {
      const key = e.key;

      if (key === codes[index]) {
        index++;

        if (index === codes.length) {
          alert("Hurray");

          index = 0;
        }
      } else {
        index = 0;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

function `init()` is never called, nor is function `onKeyDownHandler()`. One approach would be to simply remove this inner function, making sure that your `event` (`e`) has the same name that you pass into `addEventListener()`.

The following shows a working example:

```js
const codes = [
  "ArrowUp", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "ArrowDown", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "b", "a"
];

let index = 0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  const key = e.key;

  if (key === codes[index]) {
    index++;

    if (index === codes.length) {
      alert("Hurray");

      index = 0;
    }
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `init()` may not called.
Here is a working demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello</title>
    <script>
        const codes = [
            "ArrowUp",
            "ArrowUp",
            "ArrowDown",
            "ArrowDown",
            "ArrowLeft",
            "ArrowRight",
            "ArrowLeft",
            "ArrowRight",
            "b",
            "a"
        ];
        let index = 0;
        window.onkeydown = function (e) {
            const key = e.key;
            if (key === codes[index]) {
                index++;
                if (index === codes.length) {
                    alert("Hurray");
                    index = 0;
                }
            } else {
                index = 0;
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    hello
</body>
</html>
```